# Weird Asynchronous Javascript & WebMethod Behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, webmethod, pagemethods

I'm calling a PageMethod in javascript. Like this:

```
function DeleteBatchJS2()
  {$find('mdlPassword').hide();
    var pswd = $('#txtPassword').val();
    var userInfo = get_cookie("UserInfo");
    PageMethods.AuthenticateAndDelete(
        userInfo,
        pswd,
        onSuccess(),
        onError1());    
  }         

function onSuccess(result)
  {alert(result);}

function onError1(result)
  {alert(result);}
```

Now here's the strange part: One would think that calling PageMethods would give one (1) alert when running. Either the onSuccess function or the onError1 function. BUT -- I get two alerts, both saying "Undefined".

As a matter of fact, when I put a breakpoint in the VB code-behind (like the 3rd or 4th line of code in the function), I get BOTH alert boxes before I can step into my code behind. Two alerts, and THEN my code breaks.

This makes no sense to me. Am I missing anything?

Thanks,

Jason.

P.S. -- Here's the source for the WebMethod function. Please also note it does make a WCF call.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function AuthenticateAndDelete(ByVal UserInfo As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim Client As New LetterWriterClient
    Dim bo As New BatchOperations
    Dim UserNumber As String
    Dim UserName As String


    'Extract the user name and number from the user info cookie string
    UserName = GetValueFromVBCookie("UserName", UserInfo)
    UserNumber = GetValueFromVBCookie("UserNumber", UserInfo)

    'Now validate the user
    If bo.ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin("Backoffice", UserName, Password) Then
        AuthenticateAndDelete = Client.Delete_dat_BatchSQL(UserNumber)
        Client.Close()
    Else
        AuthenticateAndDelete = False
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
PageMethods.AuthenticateAndDelete(
        userInfo,
        pswd,
        onSuccess,
        onError1);    
  }
```

Comment: I removed the parenthesis, and now I get neither messagebox.

Comment: Sure enough is was. Going to post the answer so it can be indexed, but will mark yours as the answer and vote up. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the return value of your handler functions, ie onSuccess() and onError1(), pass the functions themselves, ie onSuccess and onError1.

Comment: Tried that earlier and had identical results

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  There is no way it can possibly work without this change.

Answer (score 0):

There's a stateNetworkTimeout tag involved with the sessionState. Like this:

```
<sessionState timeout="540" stateNetworkTimeout="5"></sessionState>
```

I didn't have a stateNetworkTimeout, sure enough it bombed every time.

Thanks Mrchief!